# TypeScript - Map key type with value type in function sig based on a type object

Tags: typescript, typescript-generics

Imagine having a type mapping like this:

```
type MyTypeMapping = {
  Key1: Type1;
  Key2: Type2;
};
```

and a function like this:

```
const getVal = (key: keyof MyTypeMapping) => {
  return getObjectFromStorage(key)
}
```

The expected return type of the function `getVal` needs follow from the provided key value. So, if `key === Key1`, then the expected return type must be `Type1`.

And for a closely related question, imagine if there is a function:

```
const setVal = (key: keyof MyTypeMapping, val: T) => {
  return setObjectInStorage(key, val)
}
```

How do you make the type of argument `val` dependent on the type of argument `key`? So if `key === Key2`, the the expected type of `val` must be `Type2`.

Comment: please provide reproducable example

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use an inferred generic type for that.

```js
const getVal = <K extends keyof MyTypeMapping>(key: K): MyTypeMapping[K] => {
  return getObjectFromStorage(key) as MyTypeMapping[K];
};

const setVal = <K extends keyof MyTypeMapping>(key: K, val: MyTypeMapping[K]) => {
  return setObjectInStorage(key);
};
```

Comment: Thanks for your reply! Really helpful. The only thing missing is a cast on the return value with the first function: 
`return getObjectFromStorage(key) as MyTypeMapping[K]`

Comment: Updated my answer, thought this might be necessary, but I wasn't sure what your `getObjectFromStorage()` function returns